# How to filter value in next line in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I am working in list of object. I want to iterate whole object one by one and print every index value in each line. I tried some code but I am not getting the proper output.

**StringPrint.kt**

```
fun main() {
    val newString = createData().joinToString("\n") { "${it.title?: ""} ${it.status?: ""}".trim() }
    println(newString)
}

data class Event(val title: String? = null, val status: String? = null)

fun createData() = listOf(
    Event("text 1", "abc"),
    Event("text 2", "abc"),
    Event("text 3", "abc"),
    Event("text 4", "abc"),
    Event("", null),
    Event(null, ""),
    Event(null, "3"),
    Event("null", ""),
    Event("456", "89")
)
```

**output**

```
text 1 abc
text 2 abc
text 3 abc
text 4 abc
Space Space
Space Space
3
null
456 89
```

As you can see in output I added **space keyword** which means there is whiteSpace character is present and **null**. I don't want all these.

[image]

E**xpected Output**

```
text 1 abc
text 2 abc
text 3 abc
text 4 abc
3
456 89
```

After @lukas.j suggestion I tried this

```
val newString = createData()
        .filterNot { it.title.isNullOrBlank() || it.status.isNullOrBlank() }
        .joinToString("\n") { "${it.title?: ""} ${it.status?: ""}".trim() }
 println(newString)
```

**Output.kt**

```
text 1 abc
text 2 abc
text 3 abc
text 4 abc
456 89
```

it's not printing value 3 in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val newString = createData()
  .filterNot { it.title.isNullOrBlank() && it.status.isNullOrBlank() }
  .joinToString("\n") { "${it.title?: ""} ${it.status?: ""}".trim() }
```

Comment: it's not printing the `3`

Comment: Just saw that. Replace (as I just did) the || with && in the filter clause.